# Non thread safe ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java

I am looking for a similar library as ArrayBlockingQueue. Just that, I don't need the thread safe feature (For better performance purpose) offered in it, as it is using `ReentrantLock` in the `offer(E e)` method.

What I would like is

1. A FIFO queue.
2. Has an initial capacity, where pushing new element in will fail if the queue is full.
3. Thread safety is not a requirement.

I don't find `ArrayQueue` in Java standard library. Or, am I missing any classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [BoundedFiFoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/BoundedFifoBuffer.html) in the [Common.Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) with the following properties:

- The BoundedFifoBuffer is a very efficient implementation of Buffer that is of a fixed size.
- The removal order of a BoundedFifoBuffer is based on the insertion order; elements are removed in the same order in which they were added.
- The iteration order is the same as the removal order.
- Note that this implementation is not synchronized.
- BufferOverflowException is thrown on attempt to add elements to the full buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ArrayList with simple check for 'fullness' on add? Or write simple wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ConcurrentLinkedQueue (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html for more details)

Comment: Agreed. Simple tweak around ArrayList should address the issue

Answer (score 0):

http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-2.1.1/org/apache/commons/collections/BoundedFifoBuffer.html Should suit your needs. Be careful as it always returns true from add and instead will throw if you exceed the bounds

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an ArrayBlockingQueue unless you know it won't be fast enough.  If you are sending millions of objects per second, you could consider batching them to reduce overhead.  If you have only hundreds of thousands per second its unlikely to matter.